# Will System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache dispose IDisposable items when evicted?

Tags: c#, caching, idisposable

I have a builder class that creates an instance implementing IDisposable. Whenever the item to build is already in the cache, the builder will return that instance instead. My question is, will the cache call the Dispose() method on the IDisposable items it contains when they are evicted or do I have to explicitly code that behavior on the callback CacheItemPolicy.RemovedCallback?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No `Dispose` is not called. It is easy to test.

```
public class TestClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("disposed");
    }
}

MemoryCache _MemoryCache = new MemoryCache("TEST");

void Test()
{
    _MemoryCache.Add("key",
                      new TestClass(),
                      new CacheItemPolicy()
                      {
                          AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(10),
                          RemovedCallback = (_) => { Console.WriteLine("removed"); }
                      });

}
```

Comment: @RobSiklos Please don't fix the code before testing it. It was correct. Lambda requires a parameter which I don't use. I reverted the answer.

Comment: very very sorry - I thought it was a typo

Comment: I would keep this test around as a unit test, later versions of the framework may change this behaviour, and you will like a test indicating that this has changed!

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I don't see any reason for MemoryCache to call the Dispose. I may have another reference to this object somewhere in my code and use it.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to the accepted answer that you can let items be disposed on eviction if you want. Just call the `Dispose()` method in the `RemovedCallback`.

```
public class TestClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("disposed");
    }
}

MemoryCache _MemoryCache = new MemoryCache("TEST");

void Test()
{
    _MemoryCache.Add("key",
                      new TestClass(),
                      new CacheItemPolicy()
                      {
                          AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(10),
                          RemovedCallback = (x) => { ((TestClass)x.CacheItem.Value).Dispose(); }
                      });

}
```