# How to cache an IDisposable object

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memory

Suppose I have this class:

```
public class StreamEntity : IPersistableEntity, IDisposable
{
     public Stream Stream { get; set; }

     public void Dispose()
     {
           if(Stream != null) Stream.Dispose();
     }
}
```

Now let's say I want to store an instance of this class in some kind of cache, like [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx).

After storing the entity in the cache, I proceed to dipose it.

After some time, a consumer tries to retrieve the same entity so I fetch it from the cache, but there is a little problem... The object is disposed, so I cannot read its `Stream` property (Remember we disposed it after caching it?)

Now, one way to solve this, is to never dispose the cached entities. This seems logical since they should be kept alive in memory, but what happens after expiration?

Specifically, when `MemoryCache` automatically removes an object that has expired, will it dispose it?

According to [Will MemoryCache dispose IDisposable items when evicted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969321/will-system-runtime-caching-memorycache-dispose-idisposable-items-when-evicted), `MemoryCache` **will not** dispose its cached items.

Knowing this, **How can I cache a disposable object**? When should I dispose the entities if I'm not in control of their eviction?

Comment: When you say "After storing the entity in the cache, I proceed to dispose it" I assume you mean: "After storing the entity in the cache, at some point later I proceed to dispose it". In that case, when you decide it is time to dispose that entity why would you not also remove it from the cache?

Comment: @Ladi Actually, I don't know when to dispose them. I just want them to be alive as long as the cache expiration policy requires and then I want them to be recycled appropiately. I showed the example with `I proceed to dispose it` because I wanted to reflect that a beginner developer would dispose an IDisposable entity after using it, even though it may remain in the cache.

Comment: Its not really a problem with caches, I could just as easily do `var list = new List<Stream>(); using(var fs = new File.Open(_path)) { list.Add(fs); }`, is it `List<T>`'s or `Stream`'s responsibility to handle that situation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are correct that `MemoryCache` does not call `Dispose`, however you can *tell it* to call Dispose when evicting a item.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var policy = new CacheItemPolicy
    {
        RemovedCallback = RemovedCallback,
        SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
    };
    Stream myStream = GetMyStream();
    MemoryCache.Default.Add("myStream", myStream, policy);
}

private static void RemovedCallback(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arg)
{
    if (arg.RemovedReason != CacheEntryRemovedReason.Removed)
    {
        var item = arg.CacheItem.Value as IDisposable;
        if(item != null)
            item.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The above example creates a `Stream` object and if it is unused for 5 minutes it will have `Dispose()` called on it. If the stream is removed due to a `Remove(` call removing the item or a `Set(` call overwriting the item it will ***not*** have `Dispose()` called on it.

Comment: I stand by the idea of caching contents rather than streams, but +1 for something very useful more generally.

Comment: @JonHanna I agree, that's why I gave you a +1 before I started writing it up. I just wanted to show all the options. I kinda feel bad that this got accepted instead of yours as I still think your answer is the "correct" way to handle it.

Comment: Not something I would worry about. There could after all be some reason why my answer wasn't appropriate in the wider context that prompted the question, which is precisely why your answer is great in covering other bases.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to consider is whether it's a good idea to cache such an item at all. Many disposable objects hold onto relatively limited resources, and/or some which will time-out in some way. These do not cache well, and it's best just not to do so.

On the other hand, some disposable objects don't really need to be disposable, but they share a base class with many that do, or implement an interface that needs to allow for disposal at a particular point if it is done (`IEnumerator<T>`) and so you could know that it's actually fine to not dispose it at all. In such a case you can cheerfully ignore the issue, but be careful of changes in implementation with later versions, unless the `Dispose()` is explicitly documented as safe to ignore.

Yet other possibility is to cache something that allows for quicker construction of an object, which is the approach I'd recommend with `Stream`: Don't cache `Stream` objects at all, but rather cache the bytes that could be read from it. When calling code wants to read the stream first construct a new `MemoryStream` with that byte array as the buffer. If the stream can be accessed from outside the assembly wrap that stream in another stream that enforces a read-only policy (if it is only accessible inside your own code you can skip that as an optimisation, by just being careful never to write to the stream). Then return that stream. The calling code can treat it like a stream obtained any other way (including calling `Dispose()` when it's done) but you can still give the calling code those stream faster because of the caching.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a class called `Scoped<T>` to solve this problem. You can store scoped objects in a cache, and when retrieving them create a lifetime from the scope. The scope implements thread-safe reference counting and will keep the scoped item alive (not disposed) until the cache and all lifetimes are disposed.

This is what it looks like in use, plugged into a cache:

```
int capacity = 666;
var lru = new ConcurrentLru<int, Scoped<SomeDisposable>>(capacity);
var valueFactory = new SomeDisposableValueFactory();

using (var lifetime = lru.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactory.Create).CreateLifetime())
{
    // lifetime.Value is guaranteed to be alive until the lifetime is disposed
}

class SomeDisposableValueFactory
{
   public Scoped<SomeDisposable>> Create(int key)
   {
      return new Scoped<SomeDisposable>(new SomeDisposable(key));
   }
}

class SomeDisposable : IDisposable
{
   public SomeDisposable(int key) {}
   public void Dispose() {}
}
```

The code is here on GitHub: https://github.com/bitfaster/BitFaster.Caching

```
Install-Package BitFaster.Caching
```

I use this for caching [pooled MemoryStream instances](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream), to prevent the situation you described - a consumer of the cache is a relatively long running operation, and a burst of web requests causes the LRU to fully cycle and evict the in use item. The scope keeps it alive until the last user is finished.